# Food menu legend consistency

Tags: conventions, consistency, natural-language

Should a food menu legend have "Gluten Free" and "Contains Nuts" or would it be better to be consistent with "Gluten Free" and "Nut Free" or even "Contains Gluten" and "Contains Nuts."

Each of the menu items will be marked with the appropriate symbols.

I think there is a convention to prefer "Gluten Free" in isolation, and "Contain Nuts" in isolation, but mixing them seems rather strange to me.

This menu will be for US users if that matters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Good Design Meets Users' Expectations**

'Gluten Free' and 'Contains Nuts' are the terms that have become the way to refer to these concepts in the US. If you go against this for the sake of consistency, your design will be internally consistent but inconsistent with the rest of the world.

**Help Avoid Errors**

Changing conventional terminology introduces a potential source of confusion and error, and while it sounds like hyperbole to say it, when it comes to nut allergies, mistakes can be fatal.

Possibly the reason it seems strange to you is because you're overthinking it slightly. Don't do this. Stick with convention.